# How to use build_query function of Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have to pass a query parameters with different values but absolutely equal keys. I found this `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\build_query();` But it returns only last value. For instance:

```
$array = [
       'test' => '1',
       'test' => '2'
    ]
\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\build_query($array);

//OR

http_query_builder($array);
```

It returns every time string with the last item.

Does it possible to do that with PHP? Because the side which will take these parameters just can not do anything in their side so I have to pass parameters with the equal keys.

Comment: makes not sense to send two values with the same key, your webserver will evaluate only one of the two

Comment: if you want to send more data with the same key, it must be an array like key

Comment: @Berto99 do you mean $test = [1,2]?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken you have to use `test[]` as key or `test[0]`, `test[1]`...

Comment: _“I found this \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\build_query(); But it returns only last value.”_ - you do realize that this has nothing whatsoever to do with that specific method, right? Your `$array` only contained _one_ element to begin with, because you used the same key in there twice, which means the second item has overwritten the first one.

Comment: Try `$array = [ 'test' => ['1', '2'] ];`

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much, can you type it like answer I will mark it like right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not with the specific method used, but with how you filled your array to begin with:

```
$array = [
       'test' => '1',
       'test' => '2'
    ]
```

You can not use the same array *key* twice; your array only contains *one* element now, because the second one has overwritten the existing first one under that same key.

Make the `test` element *itself* an array, that contains your two values:

```
$array = [
  'test' => ['1', '2']
];
```